# what is ~$ in linux shell scripts

Tags: shell, sh

I see the below statement in a shell script

```
if [ "$file" = "conf" ] || echo $file | grep -q '~$'; then
```

What is `~$`? I know other dollar notations like `$1 $2 $@ $$ $*` but never saw anything like `~$`.

Comment: `'~$'` is a string of two characters, `~` and `$`.

Comment: I see. Thank you. $1 is first argument.. similarly what is $?

Comment: Have you tried reading the manual for your shell?

Comment: @melpomene No, I have not tried. I did not know such thing existed. In general i googled around to check if ~$ meant something.. I will refer to it. Thanks..

Comment: If you don't know what shell you're using, it's probably bash: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html (and many things work the same way in other shells as well). `$?` is documented in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'~$' pattern in grep matches all lines that end with '~'.
So the `if` portion will be executed, if the file name ends with `~` .
Actually the entire `echo $file | grep -q '~$'` means:
Try to match if filename ends with ~, but don't print the matching results. 
If matched, execute the if part.

The '~$' does have special meaning. ie. end with ~

Comment: Nice forgot this subtle aspect.

Answer (score 0):

`~$` is a sequence of two characters and has no special beaning in `bash`.

After all why should you be bothered about `~$` in `grep -q '~$'`.

It is pretty obvious that `~$` just makes a pattern.

Regarding

> what is $ then

It has special meanings

- when used in the context of variable, say `$var`.
- when used in a regex  say`stuff$` which matches lines ending in `stuff`.

Please check [[ Special Parameters ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html).

Comment: Thank you. $1 is first argument.. similarly what is $?

Comment: I am not sure who gave it.

Comment: @mk.. : The other answer shows you a nice point by the way.. :)